How to use value from existing Workitem Field in Azure DevOps extension?
I am planning to use this extension in my Azure DevOps project. This is useful one but need to dynamically pass a field value in the URL. For example, I want to set the URL like
https://www.google.com/search?q=$(Custom.SearchText)

where Custom.SearchText is field from the work item type.
if the value is "AzureDevOps" then the URL should be https://www.google.com/search?q=AzureDevOps
if so, kindly help me with details. or if there is any other solution kindly let me know.

If you set the query URL directly like https://www.google.com/search?q=AzureDevOps, will the field populate any results? I was unable to retrieve any response from outside Azure DevOps. If yes, can you please share screenshot of your working settings?

Hi @KingRules, Have you got a chance to check the answer below? I am afraid the 3rd-party extension does not meet your requirement at the moment. Hope the information can help resolve your concerns. Thx.

Hi @AlvinZhao-MSFT, Thanks for your comment & apologizes for the lateness from my side. yes the extn doesn't help my case as I want the search text to be dynamic & picked from an field value. Problem with this extn is that there is no development activity for past few years. I will raise a feature request for this. Thanks once again for your response. Cheers

Thx for taking time to share the update and glad to know the answer helps. I agree an official extension or feature would be better considering better maintenance and support.

As far as I have tested, this extension doesn't support dynamically setting the query URL and besides, it doesn't seem to support the queries outside the current Azure DevOps organization, either.

Assuming your requirement is to search the value from certain work item field in Google and then update some field with the search results automatically, I am afraid there is no such built-in functionality in Azure DevOps at the moment.
For this, you could create a feature request via: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/report?space=21&entry=suggestion . That will allow you to directly interact with the appropriate Product Group, and make it more convenient for the product group to collect and categorize your suggestions.
